# Add, Commit and Push at Once using GULP-GIT

Tags: git, gulp

I'm trying to create a task that does `add .` , `commit`, and `push` in a single command line like : `gulp gitsend -m "My changes"`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var git = require('gulp-git');

gulp.task('gitsend', function() {
if (argv.m) {
    console.log('adding, commiting and pushing to git...');
    return gulp.src('.')
    .pipe(git.add())
    .pipe(git.commit(argv.m)
    .pipe(git.push('origin', 'master', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    })));
}
});
```

But this is not working: it throws an exception:

```
/Users/me/myproj/front/node_modules/gulp-git/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623
    var written = dest.write(chunk);
                       ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at write (/Users/me/myproj/front/node_modules/gulp-git/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
    at flow (/Users/me/myproj/front/node_modules/gulp-git/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:632:7)
    at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (/Users/me/myproj/front/node_modules/gulp-git/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:664:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at emitReadable_ (/Users/me/myproj/front/node_modules/gulp-git/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:448:10)
    at emitReadable (/Users/me/myproj/front/node_modules/gulp-git/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:444:5)
    at readableAddChunk (/Users/me/myproj/front/node_modules/gulp-git/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:187:9)
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.push (/Users/me/myproj/front/node_modules/gulp-git/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:149:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform.push (/Users/me/myproj/front/node_modules/gulp-git/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:145:32)
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

Any idea what's wrong and how can I archive my need ?
Thank you.

Comment: Part of the power of Git is the ability to separate committing code from sharing code. This allows you to commit whenever you feel it's the right time to commit without being concerned about whether you're ready to share. By combining commit and push you lose this important feature.

Comment: I removed the tags from your title. Please see [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190).

Comment: It's not tag !!! it's TITLE !!!! It's necessry to people read in an index and catch with the eyes. Your attitude is pathetic and arbitrary and non sense.

Comment: Also, gulp-git is a library made for GULP, not used as tag, but essential to the context !! ! Why instead judge with a non sense arg you at least check the code and realize "var git = require('gulp-git');" ??? It's easy to be authoritary, right ?? It's a doubt regarding a lib in particular. And I edited back no matter if you like or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can split the individual tasks out (add, commit, push) and then run them using run-sequence to ensure that add and commit are done first before pushing.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var git = require('gulp-git');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('init', function() {
  console.log(argv.m);
});

gulp.task('add', function() {
  console.log('adding...');
  return gulp.src('.')
    .pipe(git.add());
});

gulp.task('commit', function() {
  console.log('commiting');
  if (argv.m) {
    return gulp.src('.')
      .pipe(git.commit(argv.m));
  }
});

gulp.task('push', function(){
  console.log('pushing...');
  git.push('origin', 'master', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});

gulp.task('gitsend', function() {
  runSequence('add', 'commit', 'push');
});
```

Comment: Ty, Calvin ! Pretty nice !

Comment: Its the code from the documentation page.  I assume you haven't even looked at that before asking the question

Comment: @CodeWizard I am glad someone asked this question and I didn't find this in documentation yet as well. :)