# How to upload a package to a repository through webpack?

Tags: node.js, maven, webpack, deployment, gruntjs

I have a NodeJs project and i am using webpack for the packaging

Previously, I have used pom.xml for packing and deploying the artifact to the corresponding repositories (snapshot or release)  using distributionmanagement

I would like to have a Webpack task to do the deployment

Now, can i achieve the same whatever maven does in webpack or even grunt?

Also, can someone help me with the webpack/Grunt configuration to achieve this?

Comment: yes you could write a command that will deploy your code. but you could also use CI like the [gitlab-ci](https://about.gitlab.com/features/gitlab-ci-cd/) if you are using gitlab or [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/) for github.

Comment: Thanks @Miqe, Can you please also let me know the webpack task that needs to be created to upload the files. Basically, can you please let me know the configuration script to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've never did this before but here is what i if i were in you shoes.
**i haven't test the code or the concept its more of a suggestion**

first i don't think only webpack could do it by self. but with the help of gulp/grunt task runners it could be achieved.

so first install [gulp-git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-git) which will be handy for this task.  then create a gulp task that you would call letter from webpack.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');
gulp.task('add', function(){
  return gulp.src('./dist/*')
     .pipe(webpack())
    .pipe(git.add({args: '-f -i -p'}));
});
gulp.task('commit',['add'], function(){
  return gulp.src('./dist/*')
     .pipe(webpack())
    .pipe(git.commit(() => "commit message here"))
});

gulp.task('default',['commit'], function(){
  return gulp.src('./dist/*')
  .pipe(webpack())
  .git.push('origin', 'master', {args: " -f"}, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

then do this from your `webpack.config.js`

```
return gulp.src('src/entry.js')
  .pipe(webpack( require('./webpack.config.js') ))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
```

for further reference go to

- https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/usage-with-gulp to see how to integrate gulp with webpack
- [Add, Commit and Push at Once using GULP-GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188219/add-commit-and-push-at-once-using-gulp-git) to see efficient usage of gulp-git
- https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-git/blob/master/examples/gulpfile.js  gulp git examples

as i said this is more of a suggestion of how to connect the dots

Comment: you could use [grunt-git](https://github.com/rubenv/grunt-git) with [grunt-webpack](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/grunt-webpack) if you prefer grunt instead of gulp.