# Using GULP, Is it possible to upload / deploy only a single folder of my repo?

Tags: deployment, directory, gulp, task

I am asking this because my situation is the following:

I am using GULP in my web project, an I have a repository with lot of folders all of different works.

I work on one of these and when I have to deploy the files I have worked on I launch the gulp deploy and Gulp upload all the folders of the repo on the server.

Is there a way I can do it in my terminal to tell gulp to deploy ONLY the folder I have worked on and not all the folders in my repo?

I can't edit the gulp tasks, this ha s to be a thing I can do differently for every time I work on a different folder.
Thank you!

I can't edit the gulp tasks for they are very wide, the take all the files in all the folders and do the build and the build is used inside the deploy with the publish. Like this:

// BUILD ALL
gulp.task('build', gulp.series('compile', 'post-compile', 'configure-libraries'));

// DEPLOY
gulp.task('deploy', gulp.series('build', 's3-publish'));

Comment: Please provide your gulp file, at least the function that builds and publish

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188219/add-commit-and-push-at-once-using-gulp-git